# Can I create a UI using codiqa/jetstrap and then add angular keywords?

Tags: angularjs

I am a backend engineer but need to come up with a front end. Can I use Jetstrap/Codiqa and create a pretty UI using drag and drop. Can I then export the html and add the angular keywords? Is this the best practise for a non front-end person creates a UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used codiqa to design an phone app using phonegap. Codiqa generates code based on jQuery. it's possible to add angular after you export the code. Not very common to mix angular and jquery, from what I've seen though. Another online prototyping tool I recently found that generates AngularJS code (as well as Phonegap based Steroid.js) is AppGyver's [composer](http://www.appgyver.com/composer). Comes with some built in color themes (similar to jQuery) and you're able to create a mobile app quickly based on Steriods.js/Phonegap.